# Storing comma separated list in db column, how to get and set?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to store a comma separated list in a database column like:

```
234234,2134234,2453245,2345
```

I then want to get this list, and use it in a query like:

```
u = User.find("where some_id in (?)", my_comman_seperated_list)
```

I have to convert this into an array then right?

Answer (score 5):

Define your column as `text`, and in ActiveRecord declare that the column as serialized:

```
serialize :my_column
```

Now that column will be stored as `[234234,2134234,2453245,2345]`, and when you get that object, the attribute will be an array you can pass into your find.

Answer (score 1):

Is there are a reason this *must* be in a column, rather than as a separate table? It might make more sense to create a new model for the data being stored in that column, and then store one value in each row, which `belongs_to :user`.

Comment: I'm de-normalizing it for a reason yes :)